# Where can I find DownloadManager's ContentProvider implementation

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-download-manager

I've searched through android's open source code as much as I could and I haven't been able to find the implementation to the actual downloading via the DownloadManager in the 2.3 SDK. I have found the [source for the DownloadManager](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.1_r1/android/app/DownloadManager.java#DownloadManager) and the [source for a download class that has constants to interact with the ContentProvider](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.1_r1/android/provider/Downloads.java#Downloads) but I haven't been able to find the source for the `ContentProvider`.

I'm wanting to find this so that I can know a good way to implement a download of my own, since I'll be using a lesser version than 2.3 for my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to find this [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/DownloadProvider/+/master/src/com/android/providers/downloads/DownloadProvider.java). You can also get the project by cloning the [DownloadProvider](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/DownloadProvider) project and looking at the project source code. The DownloadProvider.java specifically was what I was looking for. However, the DownloadThread.java handles the heart of the download implementation, so I would recommend looking at that.

The git command is

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/DownloadProvider
```